# Equirectangular projection in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, projection, fisheye

[image: 180 degree fisheye image]
[image: I want this result]

I study a lot of resource on the internet.
I know this is a equirectangular projection.
But I have no idea how to performance this projection by OpenCV.

Both OpenCV code or Mathematica formula are OK.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look here http://paulbourke.net/geometry/transformationprojection/ then write some code and return if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks, It's helpful!